# Си работа со строками и динамической памятью

Tags: c, malloc

Сильно не пинайте, но я перечитал много литературы про эти указатели и походу так и не понял. От безысходности пишут сюда.
Кратко, мне нужно делать не большой лог в память (не файлы) во время выполнения программы и в конце вывести в консоль. Читать в комментариях то как я понял:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//  Глобальный указатель
char* pWordList = NULL;

void wordSet(char *text){
    //  Через маллок получаем новый адрес указанной длины
    char *pWordListN = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(pWordList) + strlen(text) + 1));

    //  Почему то по новому адресу уже находиться мусор из ероглифов *pWordListN

    //  Соединяем строки - новый адрес + текст из адреса по глобальному
    //  указателю, записывая в новый выделенный адрес 
    strcat(pWordListN, pWordList);

    //  Тоже самое добавляем еще указанный текст
    strcat(pWordListN, text);

    //  Тоже самое добавляем еще переход на новую строку
    strcat(pWordListN, "\n");

    //   Записываем в глобальный указатель адрес, нового указателя
    pWordList = pWordListN;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    system("chcp 1251>nul"); 

    //  Объявляем переменную 
    char wordList[] = "";

    //  К глобальному указателю указываем адрес переменной
    pWordList = &wordList;

    //  Вводим слова
    wordSet("Слово 1");
    wordSet("Слово 2");
    wordSet("Слово 3");
    wordSet("Слово 4");
    wordSet("Слово 5");

    //  Те что выше слова еще вводятся,
    //  но если добавить еще несколько то вылетает
    /*wordSet("Слово 6");
    wordSet("Слово 7");
    wordSet("Слово 8");
    wordSet("Слово 9");
    wordSet("Слово 10");*/

    //  Выводим все что получилось
    printf("%s", pWordList);

    return 0;
}
```

Распишите пожалуйста что не так и обязательно с комментированием почему.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что такое "не большой лог в память (не файлы)".
Похоже, Вы пытаетесь написать свой вариант функции realloc. Посмотрите примеры работы с этой функцией.Вот например: [www.cplusplus.com realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char wordList[] = "";
//  К глобальному указателю указываем адрес переменной
pWordList = &wordList;
```

- `wordList` - это `char*`
- `&wordList` - это `char**`
- `""` - это `const char[1]` или `const char*`
- `pWordList` - это char* (уже типы не совпадают с `&wordList`, я не уверен что вы именно так хотели)

То есть, оперируя с `pWordList` в функции `wordSet` вы на самом деле оперируете не с строкой символов, а с адресом переменной. Вы берёте от него ( от адреса переменной) функцию `strlen` (!!!) при первом вызове функции.

Первый вариант, похожий на то, что Вы хотели получить - с использованием `realloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char* pWordList = NULL;

void wordSet(const char *text){
    size_t newLen = 2;  //for '\n' and '\0'
    if (text == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s [WARNING]:try to add NULL", __FUNCTION__);
        return;
    }
    newLen += strlen(text);
    char* currentEnd = NULL;
    if (pWordList != NULL){
        newLen += strlen(pWordList);
        currentEnd = pWordList + strlen(pWordList);
    }
    pWordList = (char*)realloc(pWordList, newLen);
    if (pWordList == NULL){
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (currentEnd == NULL){
        currentEnd = pWordList;
    }
    sprintf(currentEnd, "%s\n", text);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    wordSet("Слово 1");
    wordSet("Слово 2");
    wordSet("Слово 3");
    wordSet("Слово 4");
    wordSet("Слово 5");
    wordSet("");
    wordSet("Слово 6");
    wordSet("Слово 7");
    wordSet("Слово 8");
    wordSet("");
    wordSet(NULL);
    wordSet("Слово 9");
    wordSet("Слово 10");

    //  Выводим все что получилось
    printf("%s", pWordList);
    free(pWordList);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Слово 1
Слово 2
Слово 3
Слово 4
Слово 5

Слово 6
Слово 7
Слово 8

Слово 9
Слово 10
wordSet [WARNING]:try to add NULL
```

Второй возможный вариант, без `realloc` - сделать линейный односвязный список строк.

С указателями всё просто. Представляйте память как последовательность из ячеек, где каждая ячейка - один байт. Тогда указатель - это номер ячейки.
Причём если указывать тип (`char`, `int`, `double`) то вы как бы говорите, что у вас размер ячейки - `sizeof(type)` (для `char` - свой, для `int` - свой). 
Таким образом,

```
int* s = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
s = s + 1;
```

сдвинет номер ячейки на `sizeof(int)` байт (одну ячейку) вправо.
NULL является специальным маркером, указывающим на пустой указатель - не проинициализированный.

***Важно***
Когда делаете выделение памяти (`malloc`, `calloc`, в некоторых случаях `realloc`) - не забудьте освободить память (`free`), когда она вам уже больше не нужна.